# Создание таблицы csv с данными парсинга

Tags: python, csv, beautiful-soup

Данные парсинга (BeatifulSoup использовал) нужно записать в csv файл, раскидав по столбикам и строкам. На деле получается, что pycharm данные csv-файла показывает в более-менее нужном виде, но в Excel, по всей видимости, проблемы с кодировкой. Пробовал решить через Получение данных->Из текста и т.д.(и еще пару схожих способов). Получалось только вывести текст в нужной кодировке, но по ячейкам не раскидывалось(настраивал по разному). В чем может быть проблема? Делал по видео, только другой сайт за пример взял.

Сам код

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

# Имитация реальных дейтсвий
headers = {'accept': 'text/css,*/*;q=0.1',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'}
base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru/rossiya/noutbuki?p=1'


def main_parse(headers_http, url_base):
    urls = [url_base]
    ads = []
    '''Создание сессии'''
    session = requests.Session()

    '''Эмуляция действий в браузере'''
    request = session.get(url_base, headers=headers_http)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = BS(request.content, 'lxml')
        '''Добавление страниц в список всех страниц'''
        try:
            pagination = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'pagination-item-1WyVp'})
            count = int(pagination[-2].text)
            for i in range(1):
                url = f'https://www.avito.ru/rossiya/noutbuki?p={i}'
                if url not in urls:
                    urls.append(url)
        except:
            pass
        '''Парсинг по страницам'''
        for url in urls:
            request = session.get(url, headers=headers_http)
            soup = BS(request.content, 'lxml')
            '''Парсинг данных на одной странице'''
            divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'item__line'})
            for div in divs:
                title = div.find('a', attrs={'class': 'snippet-link'}).text
                url = '{0}{1}'.format('https://www.avito.ru', div.find('a', attrs={'class': 'snippet-link'})['href'])
                price = div.find('span', attrs={'data-marker': 'item-price'}).text
                address = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'item-address__string'}).text
                date = div.find('div', attrs={'data-marker': 'item-date'})['data-absolute-date']
                ads.append({
                    'title': title,
                    'url': url,
                    'price': price,
                    'address': address,
                    'date': date
                })
    else:
        print('ERROR')
    return ads


def files_writer(ads):
    with open('parsed_ads.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a_pen = csv.writer(file)
        a_pen.writerow(('Название', 'URL', 'Цена', 'Город', 'Дата'))
        for ad in ads:
            a_pen.writerow((ad['title'], ad['url'], ad['price'], ad['address'], ad['date']))


ads_list = main_parse(headers, base_url)
files_writer(ads_list)
```

Comment: Ваш код корректен и вообще довольно хорош, просто у Excel реально трудности с пониманием CSV. Можете попробовать разные аргументы у `csv.writer`, delimiter, quotechar, [диалекты](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect) (например, `excel_tab`). Или используйте другое ПО для работы с таблицами, вроде LibreOffice, Google Sheets, они хорошо считывают CSV/TSV.

Comment: Можете попробовать сменить кодировку на `cp1251` (Windows 1251) или `cp866` (OEM 866).

Comment: Помогло Google Sheets, LibreOffice не проверял. С аргументами у ```csv.writer``` не разобрался. Сменить кодировку не получилось(или я что-то не понимаю).